# Отловить фейковый слушатель порта

Tags: сеть, администрирование, openvpn

Есть у меня сеть, изображенная на рисунке

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я с клиента поднимаю VPN туннель, получаю адрес 10.8.0.x и работаю с рабочими станциями в подсети 191.168.1.xxx. Все отлично работает. На клиенте прописывается правильный шлюз и маршрутизация.

Теперь я пытаюсь с клиента подключится на 21 порт **любого несуществующего** хоста 191.168.1.xxx сети

```pascal
function SockCheck(ARes: Integer): Integer;
begin
  if ARes = SOCKET_ERROR then begin
    RaiseSocketError(WSAGetLastError());
  Result := ARes;
end;

function TryConnect: TSocket;
var
  LAddr: TSockAddrIn;
begin
  FillChar(LAddr, SizeOf(LAddr), 0);
  LAddr.sin_family := AF_INET;
  LAddr.sin_addr.S_addr := inet_addr('192.168.1.100');
  LAddr.sin_port := htons(21);

  Result := SockCheck(socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP));
  SockCheck(connect(Result, TSockAddr(LAddr), SizeOf(LAddr)));
end;
```

И отлично подключаюсь!!! А при попытке дальнейшего вызова

```pascal
SockCheck(recv(Result, LBuf[0], Length(LBuf), 0));
```

после таймаута получаю ошибку WSAECONNRESET (10054)

При этом если я подключусь на любой другой порт, то connect честно вернет WSAETIMEDOUT (10060).

VPN туннель обеспечивается при помощи OpenVPN. VPN сервер развернут на Windows 2003 с двумя сетевыми картами (внешней и внутренней)

Если на VPN сервере запустить WireShark, то при попытке подключиться на порт, отличный от 21 (в примере подключаюсь на 80), то получается такая картина

```
1   0.000000000 10.8.0.8    192.168.1.100   TCP 66  60546→80 [SYN] Seq=0 Win=64240 Len=0 MSS=1353 WS=256 SACK_PERM=1
2   1.000936000 10.8.0.8    192.168.1.100   TCP 66  [TCP Retransmission] 60546→80 [SYN] Seq=0 Win=64240 Len=0 MSS=1353 WS=256 SACK_PERM=1
3   3.001113000 10.8.0.8    192.168.1.100   TCP 66  [TCP Retransmission] 60546→80 [SYN] Seq=0 Win=64240 Len=0 MSS=1353 WS=256 SACK_PERM=1
4   7.000823000 10.8.0.8    192.168.1.100   TCP 66  [TCP Retransmission] 60546→80 [SYN] Seq=0 Win=64240 Len=0 MSS=1353 WS=256 SACK_PERM=1
9   15.00096000 10.8.0.8    192.168.1.100   TCP 66  [TCP Retransmission] 60546→80 [SYN] Seq=0 Win=64240 Len=0 MSS=1353 WS=256 SACK_PERM=1
```

при попытке же подключиться на 21 порт, получается вот так

```
1   0.000000000 10.8.0.8    192.168.1.100   TCP 66  60578→21 [SYN] Seq=0 Win=64240 Len=0 MSS=1353 WS=256 SACK_PERM=1
2   0.000064000 192.168.1.100   10.8.0.8    TCP 66  21→60578 [SYN, ACK] Seq=0 Ack=1 Win=16384 Len=0 MSS=1460 WS=1 SACK_PERM=1
3   0.017893000 10.8.0.8    192.168.1.100   TCP 54  60578→21 [ACK] Seq=1 Ack=1 Win=262400 Len=0
```

Подключение также устанавливается, если подключаться непосредственно с VPN сервера. А с любой другой машины 192.168.1.ххх сети я получаю честный WSAETIMEDOUT.

Что это такое и как его искать?

**Update** Похоже, что OpenVPN ни при чем. Остановил OpenVPN сервер, выдернул оба сетевых кабеля. Эффект остался. Причем вообще для произвольного адреса. Перезапустил весь сервер, получил ошибку "Требуемый адрес для своего контекста неверен". Воткнул кабель с первой сетью, сервер получил по DHCP свой адрес и эффект восстановился.

Comment: странно... такое должно происходить только на неблокирующих сокетах... на обычных `connect()` должен дожидаться установки соединения и только потом возвращаться с успехом (хотя не уверен, что там в WinSock с этим)... ЗЫ: я так понимаю, на удалённом сервере огнестенка настроена на DROP пакетов на всех неожиданных портах?

Comment: *вру: для неблокирующих сокетов должно возвращаться `EAGAIN`... у тебя `connect()` должен был бы висеть до таймаута tcp-соединения (если верить гуглу, то по умолчанию 72 секунды), а потом вернуть ошибку...

Comment: @Fat-Zer Должен. Он и висит для всех портов, кроме 21. Firewall там не установлен, т.к. в Windows 2003 Firewall не совместим с режимом шлюза

Comment: огнестенка на удалённом сервере — 192.168.1.100 (или на шлюзе с openvpn)… тогда вроде всё как и должно быть… что именно не понятно? «почему ssh сбрасывает соединение при молчании клиента?» или «почему на остальных портах происходит таймаут, а не `ECONNREFUSED`?»

Comment: а... всё... перечитал — понял `192.168.1.100` на самом деле нет...

Comment: нум... первое, что приходит на ум — этот узел всё же существует... второе — на клиенте/сервере какая-то малварь, пытающаяся украсть ssh-пароли... ещё, как вариант, на сервере установлен honeypot для ssh-атак... но с учётом последнего дополнения, я бы грешил на малварь на клиенте...

Comment: @Fat-Zer такое происходит для любого хоста. 21 это не ssh, а ftp. Не важно что на клиенте - все повторяется и на сервере. Посмотрел netstat - на 21 порту слушателя нет. Завтра попробую антивирь погонять

Comment: да, перепутал... гмм... странно... ftp трафик нет вообще ни какого смысла так подменять: он и так полностью открыт... если верить wireshark'у, то SYN,ACK приходит как-то уж очень быстро — 0.06 мс — это порядок пинга на локалхосте, так что это почти наверняка что-то локальное на клиенте... может это собственно антивирус его так зачем-то фильтрует?

Comment: @Fat-Zer Антивирусов нет. Трафик я снимал на сервере. CureIt на сервере ничего не нашел. По симптомам - на сервере стоит некий улавливатель пакетов. Но пакеты на реальные FTP сервера ходят без проблем

Comment: да, похоже на то... но куда/как копать дальше у меня мыслей нет...